# Fullcalendar event using PHP to generate feed from MySql table

Tags: php, mysql, json, fullcalendar, feed

I Have a ridiculous problem but even after an entire lurking day I cannot solve it.

I have a [Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) installation and i'm trying to retrieve events data from a file (**events.php**); i load data via **Php** from a **MySql table**.

Problem:

**events won't display in my calendar if i generate the feed automatically via Php.**

**BUT**

if i write down in my file the **EXACT** Json line, **it does work properly**.

**Example:**

this is my *events.php*:

```
<?php session_start();  

header("Content-Type: application/json");

//if (!isset($id_azienda)) die();

$id_azienda = $_GET['id_azienda'];

// Includo la classe
require_once("./db.class.php");

// Creo l'oggetto database
$db = new DataBase();

// Apro la connessione al database e ne memorizzo il risultato in $open
$open = $db->OpenConnection(); 

$eventiQuery = "SELECT * FROM scadenzario WHERE id_azienda ='$id_azienda'";

// Eseguo la query e ne memorizzo il risultato in $result
$eventiList = $db->Query($eventiQuery);

$numEventi = $db->NumRows($eventiQuery);

// Chiudo la connessione al database e ne memorizzo il risultato in $close
$close = $db->CloseConnection();

/* ************* FINE CARICAMENTO DATI DAL DATABASE ***************** */


while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($eventiList)) {
    $event_array[] = array(
        'id' => $record['id_scadenzario'],
        'title' => $record['titolo'],
        'start' => $record['data_inizio'],
        'url' => $record['url']
    );
}

echo json_encode($event_array);
?>
```

that will produce:

```
[{"id":"0","title":"test titolo","start":"2012-09-11","url":"http:\\\/\\\/yahoo.com\\\/"},{"id":"1","title":"test titolo","start":"2012-09-11","url":"http:\\\/\\\/google.com\\\/"}]
```

and **it won't display anything**.

But if i **copy and paste it** into the file "*events.php*" and comment the echo line:

```
// echo json_encode($event_array);
?>
[{"id":"0","title":"test titolo","start":"2012-09-11","url":"http:\\\/\\\/yahoo.com\\\/"},{"id":"1","title":"test titolo","start":"2012-09-11","url":"http:\\\/\\\/google.com\\\/"}]
```

**it does works.**

**EDIT:** My fullcalendar implementation is:

```
var scadenzario = $('#scadenzario-calendario').fullCalendar({

    events: "./events.php",

    header: {

        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'

    },

    selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Nome dell\'evento:');
            if (title) {
                scadenzario.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            }
            scadenzario.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        //editable: true,

    theme: true,

    buttonText: {

        today:    'Oggi',
        month:    'Mese',
        week:     'Settimana',
        day:      'Giorno'
    },

    monthNames: ['Gennaio', 'Febbraio', 'Marzo', 'Aprile', 'Maggio', 'Giugno', 'Luglio', 'Agosto', 'Settembre', 'Ottobre', 'Novembre', 'Dicembre'],

    monthNamesShort: ['Gen', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mag', 'Giu', 'Lug', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Ott', 'Nov', 'Dic'],

    dayNames: ['Domenica', 'Lunedi', 'Martedi', 'Mercoledi', 'Giovedi', 'Venerdi', 'Sabato'],

    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Gio', 'Ven', 'Sab']

});
```

It's kinda foolish, IMHO.

**Notes:**

- I read that when i try to parse just one event i can have problem with square brackets: that's not my situation, i'm trying it with two events;
- I first thought about character encoding, but i've tried text/plain and application/json, both with no luck;
- the surplus of slashes in the url is due to a lack of Gn'R sleaze hard rock style in the past few years. Lol XD (I mean: that's not the point)
- **UPDATE:** I tried also to create a txt with fwrite and write the json string into the file. No luck. The only way to get the work done seems to write the code by hand into the file. Well, i might consider it as a job offer, maybe. Lol.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance :)

P.s.: Sorry for italian comments and variables in the code, but that's not the point ;)

Comment: This should help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338817/fullcalendar-events-post-method-to-php-mysql/16412333#16412333

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) Problem. It got changed or updated on the recent php versions 5.3 and 5.4. Which version are you running on? Try to figure out what values are in your `$event_array`. One thing i would also try is to [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) all the values from the database. Can't really help you without firebug or wireshark debugging.

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($eventiList)) {
  $event_array[] = array(
    'id' => utf8_encode($record['id_scadenzario']),
    'title' => utf8_encode($record['titolo']),
    'start' => utf8_encode($record['data_inizio']),
    'url' => utf8_encode($record['url']));
}
```

EDIT: LOL this should not work btw. `$event_array` is a variable that only exists in the while function. So define it in the global scope!

Comment: Thank you for your reply: I'm using php 5.3.3. I've already tried utf8 _encoding, alas. 

But with Firebug Lite for Chrome i've noticed that there is a problem with 

    GET ./events.php?start=1345932000&end=1349560800&_=1347709880459

    Params
    _ 1347709944871
    end 1349560800
    start 1345932000

    Response: null

Comment: $event_array is not the problem, it does write down the entire string with no problem... ;)

Comment: did you try defining the $event_array outside the while scope? But you dont check for GET or POST on the event.php, so normally you should just get the result...

Comment: A while loop doesn't create a new scope, as you can see here: http://codepad.org/H1U3wXZD ... but thank you for the try ;)

Comment: I also tried to write the json string without json_encode, indeed. The problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding on the top of your php script

```
header("content-type: application/json");
```

I think the problem is a missing header declaration that on some webserver may cause a different interpretation.
Also try changing the format of your php file (the script you use to serve the events to the calendar of course) to an utf-8 charset (I use notepad++ as editor -> Format -> utf-8 encode format)

Finger cross