# fullCalendar events post method to MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I am attempting to create a MySQL backed events interface, using fullCalendar and MySQL. I have tried to manipulate the examples in the fullCalendar documentation and have successfully created a events feed from my database.

I am now trying to create a `eventDrop` call which sends an events id, title and start time to the database. I used the code from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964120/how-to-http-post-http-get-and-navigate-to-another-page-using-jquery) to create the `eventDrop` call, here is the JavaScript for the whole callendar page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    /* initialize the external events
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {

        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
        };

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });                     
    });    

    /* initialize the calendar
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

            // render the event on the calendar
            // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);                

            // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
            $(this).remove();                     
        },

        // events from mysql database
        events: "/json-events.php",

        // submit to database
        eventDrop: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            var method = 'POST';
            var path = 'submit.php';
            var params = new Array();
            params['id'] = calEvent.id;
            params['start'] = calEvent.start;
             params['end'] = calEvent.end;
             params['title'] = calEvent.title;
            post_to_url( path, params, method);
  }
    });     
});
```

The PHP file I hoped would receive the POST data and insert it into the database with an end time equal to the start time plus 15 mins (edited after answer below):

```
<?php

mysql_connect("") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());

$id = $_POST["id"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$start = $_POST["start"];
$end = date(Y-m-d T H:i:s , strtotime($start)+900);

$query = "INSERT INTO `events` VALUES (`$id`, `$title`, `$start`, `$end`, ``)";
mysql_query($query);
print $query;
?>
```

The database is not receiving the event data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the conclusion I have come up with and I have no problem running this off my test and public server.
I have taken the FullCalendar and this is the format I use.

The database is real simple.

```
id integer 11 chars primary key auto-increment,
title varchar 50,
start varchar 50,
end varchar 50,
url varchar 50.
```

This is the `index.php` or `index.html` file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            events: "json.php",
            eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                    '(should probably update your database)');
            },
            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) $('#loading').show();
                else $('#loading').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    body {
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        } 
    #loading {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        right: 5px;
        }
    #calendar {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='loading' style='display:none'>loading...</div>
<div id='calendar'></div>
<p>json.php needs to be running in the same directory.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the `json.php` file.

```
<?php
mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("calendar") or die("Could not select database");


$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY start ASC");
$arr = array();

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
$arr[] = $obj;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once remove the column names in insert query and try, if you don't get then let's think about it. Do something like this

```
mysql_query(INSERT INTO `events` VALUES ('$id', '$title', '$start', '$end', ''));
```

Just print the post values before inserting, if it seems clear, then check your query.

echo the query and exit, you may get something like this

```
mysql_query(INSERT INTO `events` VALUES ('23', 'event title', 'start date', 'end date', ''));
```

Run this query to find errors if any

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I understand and have started testing my submit file with direct values and checking the database with no luck. I have changed the php file to: `$id = $_POST["id"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$start = $_POST["start"];
$end = date(Y-m-d T H:i:s , strtotime($start)+900);

$query = "INSERT INTO `events` VALUES (`$id`, `$title`, `$start`, `$end`, ``)";
mysql_query($query);
print $query ` I am getting an internal server error when passing variables directly through the url?

Answer (score 0):

`print $query` - there should be a `;` at the end

Comment: please put these kind of one line answers in comment