# fullcalendar not reading json events from mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar, json

I am trying to pre-populate fullcalendar based on the data being pulled from mysql via php. however, the event is not populating itself in fullcalendar.
My code is:

```
 function invokeNewCal(elem)
 {
    var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        var calendar = $(elem).fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true
            editable: true,
            events: {
        url: 'index.php?methodname=getevents'
        }
        });

 }
```

The method is :

```
function getevents($m,$n)
{
    echo json_encode(array('title'=>'Hello','start'=>'Wed, 10 Apr 2013 13:00:00 IST','end'=>'Wed, 10 Apr 2013 17:00:00 IST'));
}
```

Ths JSON response is:

```
{"title":"Hello","start":"Wed, 10 Apr 2013 13:00:00 IST","end":"Wed, 10 Apr 2013 17:00:00 IST"}
```

However, the event is not being shown on fullCalendar. Any idea what am I missing?

Thanks

Full Req / Resp:

```
    Request URL:
    http://localhost/linkd/index.php?methodname=getevents&start=1364668200&end=1368297000&_=1365120846819

    Request Method:
    GET

    Status Code:
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK

    Request Headers
    05:44:26.000

  X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequestUser-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0Referer:http://localhost/linkd/schooladmin.phpHost:localhostConnection:keep-aliveAccept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflateAccept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

    Sent Cookie
    PHPSESSID:cs7ai8vreh43q9otaff91kpe67

    Response Headers
    Δ23ms

  X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.21Server:Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.21Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99Date:Fri, 05 Apr 2013 00:14:26 GMTContent-Type:text/htmlContent-Length:95Connection:Keep-Alive

      Response Body
      Δ0ms

    {"title":"Hello","start":"Wed, 10 Apr 2013 13:00:00 EST","end":"Wed, 10 Apr 2013 17:00:00 EST"}
```

Comment: This is the conclusion I came up with. Maybe it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338817/fullcalendar-events-post-method-to-php-mysql/16412333#16412333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the ISO8601 standard specified in the [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/).
If you will go to the DEMO created by Mahesh Sapkal and change the dates there to the standard and both will appear.
The standard format is easy: **YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss** where the **T** is the delimiter between the the time and date.

Hope this helps

Comment: changed to ISO8601 as per the following response: {"title":"Hello","start":"2013-04-10T12:00:00","end":"2013-04-10T15:00:00"} however the event is not showing yet :)

Comment: You are missing the [] brackets. go to this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/beeeffective/AXtjr/) to see an example of the date you gave.

Comment: You should put the json_encode data as an array inside an array like so: json_encrypt(array(array('title'=>'Hello','start'=>'2013-04-10T13:00:00','end'=>'2013-04-10T17:00:00')));

Answer (score 1):

Please change the timezone from IST to EST.

```
{
      "title":"Hello",
      "start":"Wed, 10 Apr 2013 13:00:00 EST",
      "end":"Wed, 10 Apr 2013 17:00:00 EST"
}
```

Following is the demo where we have two events one is in IST and another in EST, however the EST is only displayed.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/nzFPh/)**

Comment: are you sure that the ajax request for the given url is getting fire and it's returning the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello**,
I got the same issue and the solution is that you need to use    `events: JSON.parse(yourListOfEvents)` else it won't work.

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

Check [doc](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/), you have extra braces in `events:{url:xxx}`; but also in your json_response you are encoding only one event: you need an array of them.